# Lower Bounds for Size of Independent Set in a Graph?

Tags: graphs, satisfiability, lower-bounds

I recently learnt that for any instance of a k-SAT problem with $m$ clauses and $n$ literals , we have an assignment of literals such that at least $m(1 - 2^{-k})$ clauses are satisfied.

I was wondering if we can we show a (non trivial) lower bound of the kind that any graph $G = (V,E)$ has an independent set of size $S$ where $S$ is some function in the number of vertices and edges or the like?

Since in the optimisation version we try to find a maximum independent subset, the tighter the lower bound, the better. Hence I was wondering if there is such a lower bound exists, how tight can we make it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant result is known as [Turán's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n's_theorem). It states that if a graph has less than (roughly) $n(n-1)/(2r)$ edges then it has an independent set of size $r+1$, and this is tight.

Answer (score 4):

There is also an algorithmic kind of result. Given an $n$-vertex planar graph $G=(V,E),$ one can compute in linear time an independent set of vertices of degree less than $12$ whose size is at least 
$\left\lceil\frac{n}{24}\right\rceil.$ See e.g. [Das, Goodrich, On the complexity of optimization problems for 3-dimensional convex polyhedra and decision trees](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772197000060)